# Should I use APFS for mechanical hard drives (for the startup drive) in Macs?

Tags: apfs

What's the recommended formatting for a startup HDD Mac drive? I guess HFS+ is a better option as APFS is more suited for SSDs?

Any recommendations much welcome.

Comment: IIRC macOS Mojave and later will only install to APFS, so you do not have choice as it converts HFS+ to APFS during the install. macOS High Sierra can run from an HFS+ volume; however it will not install to HFS+ on an internal drive, you have to install it to a small HFS+ Flash Drive, and start the install from the command line passing it the right argument not to convert, then image it to the internal drive. When I say small, it's one that is not much bigger than what it takes to install it. As to any other previous versions, I wouldn't run them as my primary OS anymore, so I have not tested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Are you sure you can't install High Sierra to HFS+ on mechanical HDDs?  I think it's just SSDs that would unavoidably convert to APFS.

Comment: There used to be a `--converttoapfs NO` option for `../Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/startosinstall` but it did not work for me on my MBP, but installing to a small external flash drive it did, so I then cloned the external drive to the internal drive to keep HFS+. YMMV

Comment: I mean just doing a normal install, not using Terminal etc.  All I'd like to know is if you're given the option to preserve HFS+ during 10.13 install or upgrade.  Thanks :)

Comment: NO, you are not given an option!